# In a html select tag,how to change style of partial text of enclosed option tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given the following HTML code:

```
<select>
  <option>yellow</option>
  <option>red</option>
  <option>blue</option>
</select>
```

For example, changing the color of second character in text "blue".

Comment: @BoltClock: Did you really add the sentence "Given that following html code:"? Or is the revision history lying?

Comment: @thirtydot says the same thing for me ...haha!

Comment: At max you can style the nth option using `nth-child(x)`, I don't think you can style a specific letter in the option. Unless you are willing to try a custom drop down.. but they are not going to be real `<select>`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text as Jonathon pointed out.

Comment: @thirtydot: No, apparently the OP had ninja edited it out for whatever reason just as I was fixing the Markdown. The system needs to learn about revision merging.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is currently a way to do that in CSS or (X)HTML. As "DaneSoul" pointed out, you could style the `<option>`s themselves, but you can't individually style different parts of the text inside of them.

The `<option>` tag cannot have **any** children other than a text node.

[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text) has more information, confirming this.

Comment: Yah, I now see that my unswer isn't realy what the task was...  But I suppose it can be helpfull anyway.

Comment: @DaneSoul I almost did the same, but somehow noticed `second character`.. and left a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
  <option id='option1'>yellow</option>
  <option id='option2'>red</option>
  <option id='option3'>blue</option>
</select>
```

Then add styles in CSS

```
#option3{ color: blue; }
```

If you need do it in dynamic, you can use JQuery:

```
$("#option3").css("color", "blue");
```

Comment: Read the question he want's to change the color of second character in text "blue" not change the color of text "blue".

Comment: Yah, I have unswered and then saw this detail...

Comment: oh wait.. you can use `nth-child` (`select:nth-child(2) { color: blue; }`) instead of going thru the pain of setting class/id for each options :P [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/a3UDy/)

Comment: `select:nth-child(2)` is not the same as `select :nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could be done is to create your own drop down list with DIVs, SPANs, perhaps a UL or two, and a bit of JavaScript (something like a CSS dropdown navigation menu cxould work too I suppose) then use JavaScript to set the value to be sent for your form.

Probably more work than it's worth.