# Styling two different elements in the option of HTML select tag

Tags: php, html, css

In my PHP code, I am pulling a table of two columns from the database and displaying both of them in a dropdown list. Following is the code snippet:

```
echo "<select id='isv' class='required'>";
while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){    
    echo "<option><span class='options'>" . $row[0] . "</span>&nbsp;" . $row[1] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select><br>";
```

I wanted to separate them both by styling them differently. So I wrote the following CSS:

```
.options
{
    color: red;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 15em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

However, the style is not getting applied to the options. What exactly do I need to change in this code?

Comment: If you're using Firefox, a very handy add-on to have is Firebug.

Comment: You can't have markup in an option tag

Comment: Just a heads up, but [this related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text?rq=1) would indicate that this sort of styling its platform-dependent.

Comment: @Blaine: Firebug is not showing the span element in the style section.

Comment: @jedwards: Thank you for the link. I should have come across that before posting here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<option>` elements can not be styled that way, you'll have to design your own implementation using JavaScript. Drop-down menus (`<select>`s) are mostly styled by the browser chrome, not by CSS. In addition, the `<option>` element may not have any child elements.

Here is a good reference for what you *can* style via CSS: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can make smart use of `margin` for that instead of the `<span>`.  (which won't work, needless to say)</strike>

Consider using some jQuery plugins for custom drop downs. See an example [here](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo). And also the answers tp this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721046/custom-drop-down-list-with-jquery).

Comment: Seems to be easy when you have an image along with the element. I have 2 elements in an option though.