# How do I style option text using DropKick

Tags: html, css, jquery-dropkick

I'm using [DropKick](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/) to style a select field. I need to seperate the text in the option, so that one word is floated right.

I tried this, but my `span` is stripped away:

```
<select>
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
    <option>opt3<div class="right">I need to be to the right</div></option>
</select>
```

What can I do to target certain part of an option using DropKick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <select>
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option style="text-align: right;">opt2</option>
    <option>opt3<div class="right">I need to be to the right</div></option>
  </select>
```

By using the CSS  text-align: right;

this what you mean?

Ugly alternative:

```
  <select>
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
    <option style="text-align: right;">Foo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bar&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
  </select>
```

It will "more or less" make the letters in-between space bla ect, not even sure what to call this. :)

Comment: What I need is for a line (option) in the dropdown to have the last word floated to the right.

Comment: If you want the text inside one option tag to be in left and right side with space in-between, not sure thats possible.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Is it not possible to target a single word to make it red for instance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text   they also talk about it here, it seems like you cant do what you are asking for.

Comment: No you cant target a single word and make it red, bold and all these :)