# how to write text with multiple colors in option tag

Tags: html, css, html-select, textcolor

I have a drop down list in a form (**SELECT tag**). Its contents are city titles. But I would like to show their country titles as a comment beside them too.  Is it possible to write texts between `<option></option>` tags with multiple colors?

Sample code:

```
<select name="cities">
    <option value="1">London (England)</option>
    <option value="2">Sidney (Australia)</option>
    <option value="3">Amsterdam (Netherlands)</option>
</select>
```

Imagine that I would like city titles to be **black** and (country_name) to be **gray**.

Comment: You can't, at least not with a native `<select>`. There are jQuery plugins and JavaScript modules that will do what you want, however

Comment: It currently only works on IE if you're looking for pure CSS solutions. You can color one option tag at once, not parts of it using different colors. Answering your question, you should produce a similar behaviour as `select` lists using divs or something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling part of the OPTION text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Bojangles commented, it is not valid HTML to put tags like `div` or `span` into an `option`.

However, you can use something like [this](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) (see the `showSubtext` example) to achieve what your are looking for.

Comment: It does not have what I wanted, but it was a great link because of its interesting samples ... Thank you.

Comment: Search for "showSubtext" on this page. Isn't that exactly what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I have just wrapped up some code in a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/johnny000/2j3Vt/7/), you can give a shoot if you like. I think it's a nice scratch for a select widget without using a native browser widget.

**Html**:

```
<div id="yourSelectID" class="select">
    <div class="option-selection" data-value="none">none</div>
    <div class="option-container">
        <div class="option" data-value="1" style="color:red;">One</div>
        <div class="option" data-value="2">Two</div>
        <div class="option" data-value="Whatever" style="color:blue;">1337</div>
    </div>
    <div class="option-expand">+</div>
</div>

<button>Show Selection</button>
```

**CSS**:

```
.select {
    border:1px solid #444444;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:3px;
}
.option-container {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    border:1px solid;
}
.option-expand {
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:0 5px;
}
.option-selection {
   min-height:1px;
   float:left;
    padding:0 5px;
}
.option {
    padding:5px;
    background:#FFF;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
    $('.option-selection').width($('.option-selection').next('.option-container').width()-10); 
    $('.option-expand').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().children('.option-container').slideToggle();  
    });

    $('.option').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        var value = $this.attr('data-value');
        var name  = $this.text();
        $parent = $this.parent().parent().children('.option-selection');
        $parent.html(name);
        $parent.attr('data-value', value);
        $optionContainer = $this.parent();
        $optionContainer.slideToggle(); });


    function getSelection(id){
        $selection = $('#'+id).children('.option-selection');
        var name = $selection.text();
        var value = $selection.attr('data-value');
        return {name: name, value: value}; };

    $('button').click(function(e){
        var result = getSelection('yourSelectID');
        alert('Selection name: '+ result.name +' Selection value: ' + result.value); });
```