# How can i add more than one colored text styles to my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, text, styles

```
let combo = document.getElementById("string_determine");
let div =  document.getElementById("mybox");
```

// I'm learning javascript. I would like to be able to add multiple colored text in my javascript. I would like the "This is black" text to be in black color and "This is blue" to be in blue color. As currently they both display as blue.

```
let string_determine;

switch(combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text){
    case '"blueblue"':
    string_determine = "This is black" + "This is blue"; div.style.color = "blue";  break;
```

Comment: checkout the [switch documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: this question is not about `switch-statement`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to write text with multiple colors in option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372476/how-to-write-text-with-multiple-colors-in-option-tag)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for switch statement. You can try surrounding the text with a span element with a style property of the color you want:

[image: output]

```
function setTextColor(element, text, color) {
  const elementContent = element.innerHTML;
  if (elementContent.search(text) !== -1) {
    const coloredElement = `<span style="color: ${color}">${text}</span>`;
    const newElementContent = elementContent.replace(text, coloredElement);
    element.innerHTML = newElementContent;
  } else {
    console.error(`Cannot find text "${text}" in the given element`);
  }
}

const combo = document.getElementById("string_determine");

//      Text Element | Text to Stylize | Color (Any format of color supported in CSS)
//           -----      -------------   -----
setTextColor(combo,     "This is red",  "red");
setTextColor(combo,    "This is green", "#00ff00");
setTextColor(combo,     "This is blue", "rgb(0, 0, 255)");
```