# DropDownList Items with Html content

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

So I am adding items to a `DropDownList` from code behind, and I need those items to have an html content.

I add the items as follows:

```
ListItem _item = new ListItem("<span style='color:red;'> some item</span>", "someValue");
DDL.Items.Add(_item);
```

But the rendered html turns out like this:

```
<li>&lt;span style='color:red;'&gt; some item&lt;/span&gt;</li>
```

How do I alter the `innerHtml` of the `ListItem`s from code behind? Or is there a better way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, not because of your code or ListItem, but because you can't put html in select option.
[Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11237807/20126)
[Styling part of the OPTION text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3354979/20126)

Comment: i see, thank you. is there any workaround i can use to achieve it?

Comment: I think you will need to search for a custom dropdown, something which render something else not select-options