# bootstrap-select wrong selection made to options

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

Here is my snippet :

```
<form action="/Section/Save">
<select class="selectpicker show-tick" id="CourseID" name="CourseID">
    <option>Pick One</option>
            <option value="1" title="Microsoft Office" data-content="<ul class='select-ul'><li class='text-green'>1</li><li>Microsoft Office</li></ul>">Microsoft Office</option>
            <option value="2" title="DTP" data-content="<ul class='select-ul'><li class='text-green'>2</li><li>DTP</li></ul>">DTP</option>
            <option value="4" title="Microsoft Office" data-content="<ul class='select-ul'><li class='text-green'>4</li><li>Microsoft Office</li></ul>">Microsoft Office</option>
            <option value="5" title="Microsoft Office" data-content="<ul class='select-ul'><li class='text-green'>5</li><li>Microsoft Office</li></ul>">Microsoft Office</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The problem is, every time I open the dropdown list, wrong item is selected (or) in some cases, nothing is selected

Comment: Are you providing some kind of variable to automatically select an item from the dropdown list? Your form seems to work just fine, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Dropdown list is supposed to select the last item the user has selected when the use opens the dropdown menu. In my case,  it is not selected (or) wrong item is being selected.

Comment: If you aren't storing the value anywhere or marking any value as "selected", then it's not going to automatically select anything but the first option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element

Comment: The code works fine when the page first load. It is not working properly when user select other option. I am using this [library](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#custom-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of struggling with the problem, I have finally been able to identified the cause. It's because the `<ul></ul>` tag in the `data-content` is messing up with the index of elements in the library. So, I have to avoid to use `<ul></ul>` in the `data-content` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more in depth on your problem and what you want helped with?

I did my best to try and understand what it was you're asking, is this what you were looking for?

```html
<form action="/Section/Save">
  <select class="selectpicker show-tick" id="CourseID" name="CourseID">
    <option>Pick One</option>
    <option value="1" title="Microsoft Office" style="color: green">
      1 Microsoft Office<
    </option>
    <option value="2" title="DTP" style="color: green">
      2 DTP
    </option>
    <option value="3" title="Microsoft Office"style="color: green" >
      3 Microsoft Office
    </option>
    <option value="4" title="Microsoft Office" style="color: green">
      5 Microsoft Office<
    </option>

  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Are HTML tags supported inside <option> tag?

Comment: Nope, look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text)
The <option> element is only for Dropdown list items
although if someone does <option id="option-id"> then they can customize the option

Comment: Of course it doesn't have to be an id, could be a class, or in the example: inline styling.

Comment: I am using this [library](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#custom-content)

Comment: Are you trying to make a specific character green then? You could try doing just: data-content="<span style="color:green">1</span>" . But trying to do a list inside a list item won't work.

Comment: did a bit of digging. the class name selectpicker is deprecated, use bootstrap-select. And the data-content method is deprecated now

Comment: If that is, can you provide the correct technique of usage since I need to display rich information within option tag.
With best regards..

Comment: Instead of trying to use form/select/option use a dropdown div. Can you be more thorough on what you're trying to do with this? Is it for like a contact form? or some kind of votes?

Comment: If this is trying to  get/post data then use this as a base model [Bootstrapv4 Forms](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a value as "selected", so that it appears as the first option when the user opens the page, you need to have stored the value and then check for it. An easy way to do this in PHP would be as follows (remember you have to have stored the value previously and be checking for it):

```
  <select>
    <option>Default if none pre-selected</option>
    <option <?php if($this_value=='this_option_value') { echo 'selected="selected"' }; ?> value='this_option_value'></option>
    <option <?php if($this_value=='this_option_value2') { echo 'selected="selected"' }; ?> value='this_option_value2'></option>
  </select>
```

Related answer: [How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)

Comment: Yes. But in this case, it is not normal select, it is the modified bootstrap-select [Bootstrap-Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Comment: But don't you still have to set it to "selected" in a normal way, or at least do some kind of Javascript to set the value? (i.e., `$('.selectpicker').val('2');` will set the current value of the dropdown). Looking at docs for Bootstrap-Select, I don't see you doing anything aside from the data-content attribute.