# How do I change color of specific text in option tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a list of select options, each having its text contents

```
<select>
  <option>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</option>
  <option>Quisque vitae odio leo</option>
  <option>Aenean consequat nisl sit amet</option>
</select>
```

How do I format a specific text, say first word, in a different color, i.e. "Lorem", "Quisque", "Aenean" will be in color blue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling part of the OPTION text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text)

Answer (score -1):

Put the words inside a span tag and style the span

```
<option><span style = "color : red;">Lorem</span></option>
```

Comment: A `<option>` cannot contain tags inside of it.