# Breakline in Datalist HTML not working

Tags: php, html, sql

```
<input type="text" list="req" name="req" style="width:350px; height:70px;"><datalist id="req">
    <option value=""><option>
    <?php  while($getreq = $requirements->fetch_array()){ ?>
    <option><?=$req = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br/>',$getreq['req']);?></option>  
    <?php  } ?>
</datalist>
```

I have this query from database with 50rows, some rows the text have breakline. But the thing is when I check the datalist the breakline doesn't work.

ex:

No1 - Visible Fracture(s) of the center member.2 - The center member separates.3 - Loses air pressure in 1 minute.

but in my database it's like this.

No
1 - Visible Fracture(s) of the center member.
2 - The center member separates.
3 - Loses air pressure in 1 minute.

Any idea how to solve my problem.?

```
   Database
   ID     Req
   1      Bead Unseating Test Min. 9100 N
   2      Breaking Energy Test Min. 113 N.m. (J)
   3      No<br/>1 - Visible Fracture(s) of the center member.<br/>2 - The center member separates.<br/>3 - Loses air pressure in 1 minute.


  Must be Output in datalist or Select Option (Dropdown Menu)
  Bead Unseating Test Min. 9100 N
  Breaking Energy Test Min. 113 N.m. (J)
  No
  1 - Visible Fracture(s) of the center member.
  2 - The center member separates.
  3 - Loses air pressure in 1 minute.
```

Comment: *nl2br()* ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php ... not sure it'll help inside an `<option>` though - never tried it in a `<datalist>` but normally **no** other markup is allowed inside `<option>` tags.

Comment: it doesn't work @CD001 so any dropdown list i can use to have this work?

Comment: The PHP might be working, view source, but you can't put any other markup inside `<option>` tags as far as I'm aware, including `<br />` tags - so those tags might be in the source code but they'll do nothing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text

Comment: ... I've no idea whether this will work either but try leaving the newline characters as they are but apply `pre` styling to the option, e.g. `<option style="white-space: pre;"><?= strip_tags($getreq['req']); ?></option>`

Comment: yes seems <br/> doesn't work in Select Option and Datalist. I have no idea how to make it work. sadly

Comment: still not work @CD001

Answer (score 1):

Probebly you need `nl2br()` instead of `preg_replace()`

Check [PHP.NET manual page Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Edited Answer

`<option>` does not accept 
 so if you want

```
<select>

<option>1</option>

<option>2</option>

<option>2</option>

</select>
```

Here you need to make change

```
<?
$optarray  = explode("<br>", $getreq);

foreach($optarray as $optval){ ?>
<option><?= echo $optval; ?></option>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: ok, this seems that you are passing data in single <option> and here <br> does not work

Comment: yes the datalist and select option bypass the <br/> and all they goes to same line. I keep searching still I can't find any solution.

Comment: doesnt work, btw No1 - Visible Fracture(s) of the center member.2 - The center member separates.3 - Loses air pressure in 1 minute. this is in 1row only

Comment: Can you show me how your data saved in database? and also Final output you want?

Comment: I have made small change in my explode () you can try that. After explode () you will get an array of all your result and than you can use foreach() loop to have <option>

Comment: It works BUT, 
No
1 - Visible Fracture(s) of the center member.
2 - The center member separates.
3 - Loses air pressure in 1 minute.

this 1 row in database Became 3Rows. 

What Im trying to output is for example. I select "No" the first line it will display all the content. I don't want it to separate and make it array