# CSS for Dropdown List Text

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to style only the first word of an ASP.net DropDown list item?

For example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddCategory" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">**Other** (Something/Notething)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">**Life** (Love/Hate)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">**Companies** (Apple/Samsung)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Cars (Toyota/Honda)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Flowers (Roses/Lillies)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Desires (Pitbull/Hotdog)</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Is there a way to style (bold) the main words not in parenthesis?

And no this is not a Duplicate of [Styling part of the OPTION text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text). Nothing on there matches this. I have tried putting the desired words in  tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling part of the OPTION text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text)

Comment: You'd better show generated HTML then server tags.

Comment: Are these generated dynamically, if not wrap the desired text in a span and make it bold

Comment: this is ASP.net. it was the first thing i mentioned. i did try wrapping the desired text in span and b tags.