# How to set CSS for select and its dropdown menu when selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a backend developer, learning frontend, new to CSS.

Working on a project, have to set a default CSS for `select` tag. However on click over this tag border color is getting changed to blue from green and text color to black from green. Tried to find out CSS implementing on click however no use. All that is visible on inspect element is some event is active on `select`. Tried to add my own event on click and change CSS back, however not able to achieve it so.

CSS:

```
.customSelect {
    border-radius: 1.25rem;
    height: calc(5.25rem + 2px);
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: #00a082;
    border: 3px solid #cbece5;
}
```

Tried to add same class on custom click event, however something else is replacing my CSS.

JS:

```
$("#selectId").click( () => {
    $("#selectId").addClass('customSelect');
});
```

How to add custom CSS on `select` tag and also on its `option` drop-down menu?

**EDIT** Why not a duplicate for [how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

My question is not to style `option` tag, but to stop my `select` box from changing border color to blue like when we click on `select` or in `input` tag and by default these changes to blue. Like comment, question title, question body and answer box all changes border color to blue when clicked. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Look for the :active selector in your css

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text bottom line: you cannot style `<option>`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's a different question, I'm not trying to add CSS to `option` tag. Please read question carefully, I'm asking for `select` tag and the `dropdown` menu for `select` not `options`

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree on this that dropdown is browser functionality and thus can t be changed, but that's not the only question.

Comment: I read it, and you specifically talk about styling `select` and `option` elements. However, it appears, after your edit, that you're not talking about borders, but rather the `outline` property. That's done the same across all elements that are focusable: [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1457849)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. This blue color and click over *input*, *select* and *textarea* tag is due to *bootstrap* CSS. Removed the class `form-control` from *select* and added following class. Everything is working fine now.

CSS:

```
/* Customized Select Box */
.customSelect {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 0.5rem solid #cbece5;
    border-radius: 1.25rem;
    color: #00a082;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    height: 3.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
    width: 100%;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition-property: border-color, box-shadow;
    transition-duration: 0.15s, 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is hard to find some CSS, try to inspect an element with `:active` or `:hover`, etc., states:

[image]

Comment: This is good to know.

Comment: Good to know or not, it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment on the question as it does not solve the issue at hand.

Comment: It does relate to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to build one yourself, because accessing the individual elements of the select element is complicated. I hope someone can provide a better answer, but in case not: W3 Schools has a documented method that is pretty heavy.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

(Sorry about the link; edited)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS pseudo class to assign different values to an element.

In your case you could use:

`.customSelect:hover` to assign styles upon hovering with the mouse.

`.customSelect:active` to assign styles after clicking on something.

`.customSelect:focus` to assign styles to elements targeted by the keyboard or activated by the mouse.

This would be a separate style to the original `.customSelect` like so:

```
.customSelect {
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  height: calc(5.25rem + 2px);
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #00a082;
  border: 3px solid #cbece5;
}

.customSelect:hover {
  new-styles: new value;
}
```

You can also chain these together:

```
.customSelect:hover, .customSelect:active {
  style-to-apply-to-both: value;
}
```

Learn more about selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp