# How do I make a select option wrap when it exceeds the max width?

Tags: html, css, dropdown

For example, I have something like this:

[image]

With the following HTML code, I set the max width of the entire dropdown to be 80%, which I expect to affect each of the options.

I want to have it so that long options wrap around at the max point:

Where the red lines indicate what is considered "one option", and thus when I hover over it, everything in between the red lines should be selected

```
<select name=countries style="width:100%;max-width:30%;">
    <option value=gs selected="selected">All</option>
    <option value=gs>This is fine</option>
    <option value=gs>This message should wrap because it is very long</option>
    <optgroup label="Title">
        <option value="optcheck">Option groups are long, so they should wrap too</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pxl70474/x7w85fnm/

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you can modify the styles of the `option` tag as it's presented native to the platform. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap you can use the bootstrap selectpicker class with the data-content attribute.

```
 <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" 
     id="subject_teacher_drop_down">
   <option data-content="English" title="English">English</option>
   <option data-content="Methodology of social..."  title="Methodology of social science 
     with special reference to economics">
     Methodology of social science with special reference to economics
   </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: data-live-search="true" attaribute will not work after using this

Answer (score 4):

To make word wrap, try this css to extend height of container to make enough space to wrap text.

```
option {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot in fixing BS dropdown length issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could try rewriting it like this. I pulled this out of W3Schools. This simply writes the select menu for a responsive view. You could apply it for your site as it does wrap the text. Or figure out some other way to apply it to your site.

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 0; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:500px;">
  <select>
    <option value="0">HTML5</option>
    <option value="1">Option groups are long, so they should wrap too</option>
    <optgroup label="Title">
      <option value="optcheck">Hypertext Markup Language, a standardized system for tagging text files to achieve font, color, graphic, and hyperlink effects on World Wide Web pages.</option>    
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is not a simple solution, it does exactly what I needed it to do.  No bugs or issues at all! It's responsive and has accommodated text options of all lengths.

Comment: As a follow on, is there anyway to copy data attributes from the "original" options to the 'select-selected' and hidden 'select-items' divs?  Using jquery, I need to access the data attribute when the option is chosen and the divs don't have the data attributes supplied to the original <option>.

Comment: Hello, why the Group title does not appear in this custom select?

Answer (score 1):

This simple change worked for me.

```
option {
     white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Pulin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10123168/pulin-jhaveri)

To get this to work in Firefox, I needed to target the `:before` pseudoelement:

```
option:before {
  white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

This let my multi-select options take up more than one line of text!

Answer (score 0):

Having been unable to use other suggestions successfully, I went with the [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) component. Obviously, only useful if you are using React, but it's a very decent/attractive and easy solution if you are.