# October CMS- Language Picker Component Twig

Tags: php, twig, components, octobercms

I am trying to add flag icons for languages to my options in for loop. 
So far, I got this:

```
{{ form_open() }}
    <select name="locale" data-request="onSwitchLocale" class="form-control languageSwitcher">
        {% for code, name in locales %}
            <option value="{{ code }}" {{ code == activeLocale ? 'selected' }}>{{ name }}</option> 

        {% endfor %}

    </select>
{{ form_close() }}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you describe what's not working for you

Comment: I can't seem to figure out, how to add <i class="flag-sk"></i> for example, for my option in language drop-down. I am still learning Twig and PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - well at least not by using the option html. An option html element can not have non text child elements or be styled.

See the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text)

You can write your own custom html select/drop down/combo box and there are also many available 3rd party components that allow customisation. However out of the box the basic option element in the select html only allows a text node as a child element.