# PHP select dropdown menu multiple columns, multiple colors

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, colors, multiple-columns

I have a php html  drop-down with multiple columns. I want to apply each column different color.

```
<select name="comp">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Company</option>
<option value="">Item - Company</option>
</select>
```

Expected Result : 
"Item" should be in Red color
"Company" should be in Green Color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling part of the OPTION text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text)

Comment: I think there isn't a native solution in html or css, but you can use a javascript plugin like https://selectric.js.org/