# Why is Styling not working in option tag?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

```html
<label for="extras">Extras</label>
<select id='extras' class="form-control form-control-sm">
    <option>None</option>
    {% for ex in extra %}
        <option>
            <span>
                <div>{{ ex.itemname }}</div>
                <div style='float: right; font-weight: bold; color:green;'>${{ ex.smallcost }</div>
            </span>
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I have applied some styling to the cost but it is not working, you can see in the image below.

[image: -]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `<option>` tags [cannot have any HTML markup inside them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements). Moreover, [only a few basic CSS styles can be applied to them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7208825/4935297).

If you want to style your `<option>`s, your best option is creating your own custom select box. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27011891/4935297) on a similar question.)