# Styling text inside a select option field using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS and I was wondering if there is any way to control the text styling inside a select option field?  Or am I at the mercy of the browser?

This is my code and I am trying to stylize the text inside the  tag.

```
...
@foreach($generators as $generator)
    <option value="{{$generator->id}}">{{$generator->generator_name}}, <span class="text-indigo-900">{{$generator->generator_street_address_one}}</span></option>
@endforeach
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling part of the OPTION text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text)

Comment: Any insights on this yet?