# Bootstrap Badge Inside Select Option

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

I have following drop-down :

```html
<select class="form-control">
  <option value=1>Pooja Parikh</option>
  <option value=2>Poorti Parikh</option>
  <option value=3>Agent 2</option>
  <option value=6>AWS Bot AWS Bot</option>
</select>
```

I want the above dropdown with a bootstrap badge, like following

```html
<select class="form-control">
  <option value=1>Pooja Parikh</option>
  <option value=2>Poorti Parikh</option>
  <option value=3>Agent 2</option>
  <option value=6>AWS Bot AWS Bot <span class='badge badge-info'>Bot</span> </option>
</select>
```

when I tried the above code, its giving simple dropdown options with text only (not giving badge)

I was wondering if anyone one helps me out to implement the above.

Thanks

Comment: Well, you can't do this. You should create a custom select box instead. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text) could help.

Comment: Did you added bootstrap CSS library?

Comment: @MH Habib yes already added

Comment: Can you allow dropdown instead of select?

Comment: can you give me an example?