# How can I change the color of partial text in dropdown's <select> tag

Tags: html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Consider my code as below:

```html
<select id="TestStatus">
  <option value="0">Active <span style="color:#0823fa;">*</span></option>
  <option value="0">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

Here, I want to change the color of '*' to 'blue' but it is not working.
Can anyone please suggest to me how to achieve this UI?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not possible to insert other DOM-ELements inside of a option-tag.
[image]

This is how a browser is rendering your code (i only added your missing ' " ').

```
<select id="TestStatus">
   <option value="0">Active <span style="color:#0823fa;">*</span></option>
   <option value="0">Inactive</option>
  </select>
```

You can edit the option-elements style using css but you cant add anything then text inside of it. Here you can read more about the specification of the option tag:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`<option>` tag can't contain other HTML tags, you can inspect your HTML code and see that the `<span>` element you added isnt there

this has much more details here [Styling part of the OPTION text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text)

and here is a JS fiddle example of how you can create your own dropdown select

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTHkQ/850/