# How do I set color for specific word in select option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have select option here. I want to put color but not for all of them. Just little part of an option.

```html
<select>
  <option>I want to set color
    <font class="text-dark-danger">here</font> and Not here.</option>
  <option>I want to set color
    <font class="text-dark-danger">here</font> and Not here.</option>
</select>
```

Is there any way I can make it happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling part of the OPTION text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. you can't **Options** styling doesn't work.

In this case, you need to create customized select options.

here you got some idea-

- [Styling part of the OPTION text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354979/styling-part-of-the-option-text)

Comment: Instead of writing this as an answer you should mark this question as a duplicate.